# ESLint: Assigment will be lost -- is this legit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I wrote this little React hook:

```
type Callback = () => void

function useElementEffect<T extends Element>(callback: (el: T) => (Callback | void)) {
    let cb: Callback | void
    return useCallback((el: T) => {
        if(el) {
            cb = callback(el)  // <-- eslint error here
        } else if(cb) {
            cb()
        }
    }, [])
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
function CenterCanvas() {
    const [[width, height], setSize] = useState([300, 150])
    const ref = useElementEffect((div: HTMLDivElement) => {
        const obs = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
            for(const entry of entries) {
                const contentBoxSize = entry.contentBoxSize[0]
                setSize([
                    Math.floor(contentBoxSize.inlineSize),
                    Math.floor(contentBoxSize.blockSize)
                ])
            }
        })
        obs.observe(div)
        return () => obs.disconnect()
    })

    return (
        <$Center ref={ref}>
            <TheCanvas width={width} height={height}/>
        </$Center>
    )
}
```

It's working great, but I'm getting an ESLint error on the  `cb = callback(el)` line:

> ESLint: Assignments to the 'cb' variable from inside React Hook useCallback will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useCallback.(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

However, `cb()` seems to invoke perfectly fine when `CenterCanvas` is unmounted. No errors. So `cb` does seem to live long enough to be invoked, even if it's overwritten again on the next render (which I want).

Should I just ignore the warning, or is there some scenario where this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2):

`useCallback` memorizes your callback and has no declared dependencies (`[]`), and your callback captures the `cb` variable so it works in your case.

If you were to update your custom hook to accept an array of dependencies, it would break though so I suggest you follow `eslint` suggestion of using a ref.